# Non-compressed, non-minimal grammar for programming language C

Tags: c, grammar, bnf

Programming languages are defined via a grammar, e.g. Java is defined in the JLS, see [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/syntax.html#18.1)

This is a minimal, "compressed" grammar, no construct is used twice: the result are - for me - unuseful grammar descriptions like *MethodDeclaratorRest* which is appended to the *MethodOrFieldDecl* as you can see here, I'd call it the "minimal,compressed approach"

```
MethodOrFieldDecl:
        Type Identifier MethodOrFieldRest

MethodOrFieldRest:
        VariableDeclaratorRest
        MethodDeclaratorRest

MethodDeclaratorRest:
        FormalParameters {[]} [throws QualifiedIdentifierList] ( MethodBody |   ; )
```

This is in general ok, but I'd like to have a grammar like the following where all the necessary information of the type *MethodDeclaration* are listed, I'd call it the "top-down-approach":

```
MethodDeclaration:
   [ Javadoc ] { ExtendedModifier }
          [  ]
        ( Type | void ) Identifier (
        [ FormalParameter 
             { , FormalParameter } ] ) {[ ] }
        [ throws TypeName { , TypeName } ] ( Block | ; )
```

Searching for a "top-down grammar approach I found the website of Pete Jinks, using the "minimal,compressed approach": [here](http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~pjj/bnf/c_syntax.bnf)

**Now, I'd like to have a grammar definition of the programming language C using the "top-down-approach".**

Comment: The syntax that's being used is pretty standard; it's called BNF (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form).  It makes it relatively easy to define parsers.

Comment: thx for answer, i know the bnf but as you can see, there are several solutions to define a language grammar. the two approaches use two different versions, but the first one won't work for me. if i spent much time, i could convert from the minimal grammar to a non-minimal one. problem: 1. don't have the time, 2. can't be sure if i didn't miss anything

Comment: I guess my question is *why* the first version won't work for you; what is the application for the grammar, and why do you need it in the second form?  Are you trying to build a parser?  And if so, why is the typical BNF form unsuitable?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a readily available source for that form, but it is fairly straightforward to take a BNF version of the grammar as a text file and perform a series of copy-paste operations to convert to that form.
http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~pjj/bnf/c_syntax.bnf is the basic form of the C language grammar.

One problem with the 'top-down approach' is you need to decide a level to expand that is useful.  But would it *really* be useful to have a single definition of the translation_unit to all that detail?  I agree that some smaller range expansions could be useful.  For example, I think function definition broken out to at least the statement level could help understanding.

On the other hand, BNF is very common and learning to read that form is a skill worth learning...

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

"The C Programming Language" by Kernighan and Ritchie 2e (pub. Prentice-Hall) has an (E)BNF grammar in it... there may also be a version accessible online.